# Need to add 3 custom exception classes

Tags: java, class, exception

I have made a TicTacToe game that works to an extent, I am still ironing out the last few kinks in the program. I want to add 3 customers exception classes, which are IncorrectEntryException, PlayerOutOfTurnsException and StalemateException. The IncorrectEntryException must be thrown when a user enters a character other than an X or an O into the game interface; the PlayerOutOfTurnException must be thrown when a user attempts to play an X when the system is expecting and O (or visa versa); the StalemateException must be thrown when all the game cells are full and no three-in-a-row has been achieved.

I will add the code for my program, it has two classes, GameGUI and GameLogic.

```
    import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 

    public JTextField b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;
    JPanel p, p2;
    JButton check;

    GameGUI() { 
        // create components
        Container c = getContentPane();
        p = new JPanel();
        p2 = new JPanel();
        check = new JButton("Check game.");
        check.addActionListener(this);

        b1 = new JTextField(null, 1);
        b2 = new JTextField(null, 1);
        b3 = new JTextField(null, 1);
        b4 = new JTextField(null, 1);
        b5 = new JTextField(null, 1);
        b6 = new JTextField(null, 1);
        b7 = new JTextField(null, 1);
        b8 = new JTextField(null, 1);
        b9 = new JTextField(null, 1);

        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);
        p.add(b3);
        p.add(b4);
        p.add(b5);
        p.add(b6);
        p.add(b7);
        p.add(b8);
        p.add(b9);
        p2.add(p);
        p2.add(check);
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        c.add(p2);

        setSize(150, 150);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new GameLogic();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

    }
}
```

break

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GameLogic extends GameGUI implements ActionListener {



int counter; // count turns
String letter = ""; 
boolean winner = false;


GameLogic() {

}

public static void main(String[]args) { 

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if(e.getSource()==check) {      

        // Horizontal wins.

        if(b1.getText().equals(b2.getText()) && b2.getText().equals(b3.getText()) && !(b1.getText().equals(null))) { 
            winner = true;
            letter = b1.getText();
        }
        else if(b4.getText().equals(b5.getText()) && b5.getText().equals(b6.getText()) && !(b4.getText().equals(null))) { 
            winner = true;
            letter = b4.getText();
        }
        else if(b7.getText().equals(b8.getText()) && b8.getText().equals(b9.getText()) && !(b7.getText().equals(null))) { 
            winner = true;
            letter = b4.getText();
        }

        // Diagonal wins.

        else if(b1.getText().equals(b5.getText()) && b5.getText().equals(b9.getText()) && !(b1.getText().equals(null))) {
            winner = true;
            letter = b1.getText();
        }
        else if(b3.getText().equals(b5.getText()) && b5.getText().equals(b7.getText()) && !(b3.getText().equals(null))) { 
            winner = true;
            letter = b3.getText();
        }

        // Vertical wins.

        else if(b1.getText().equals(b4.getText()) && b4.getText().equals(b7.getText()) && !(b1.getText().equals(null))) { 
            winner = true;
            letter = b1.getText();
        }
        else if(b2.getText().equals(b5.getText()) && b5.getText().equals(b8.getText()) && !(b2.getText().equals(null))) { 
            winner = true;
            letter = b2.getText();
        }
        else if(b3.getText().equals(b6.getText()) && b6.getText().equals(b9.getText()) && !(b3.getText().equals(null))) { 
            winner = true;
            letter = b3.getText();
        }
        else { 
            winner = false;
        }

        if(winner == true) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Winner is " + letter);
            b1.setText("");
            b2.setText("");
            b3.setText("");
            b4.setText("");
            b5.setText("");
            b6.setText("");
            b7.setText("");
            b8.setText("");
            b9.setText("");
        }

        else if(winner == false) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stalemate!!");
            b1.setText("");
            b2.setText("");
            b3.setText("");
            b4.setText("");
            b5.setText("");
            b6.setText("");
            b7.setText("");
            b8.setText("");
            b9.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am sorry if I was not clear, English is not my native language. I need to learn how to create and add these exception classes.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I create a custom exception class to check what I listed above, Stalemate, no more turns and incorrect entry (not x / o) sorry if I wasn't clear, English is not my native language.

Comment: I doubt creating custom Exceptions is the best solution for your case, because Exceptions are meant to be used to handle **unexpected** behaviors

Comment: Go read this - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, you want to create custom exception class. This is easy, just create a public class which extends `Exception` class, like this:

```
public IncorrectEntryException extends Exception {

   public IncorrectEntryException() { }

   public IncorrectEntryException(String message) {
       super(message);
   }
}
```

Now you can use it as below:

- Throwing your custom exception:

  `throw new IncorrectEntryException();`
- Catching your custom exception:

  ```
     try {

       //Code

     }
     catch(IncorrectEntryException e) {
      //Do something with your exception
     }
  ```

You can create other exception classes similarly. There are cases like Checked and Unchecked exceptions, but in your case I think this should suffice. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To create `custom exception classes`, you can either extend `Exception` class or `RuntimeException` class depending upon `checked/unchecked exceptions` type.

So for example, If you want to create an `unchecked exception` NewRuntimeException then it can be done like this.

```
class NewRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {
    public NewRuntimeException() {
        super();
    }
}
```